# How can I subtract a single iteration of System.out.print in a recursive loop?

Tags: java

I want the output to be something like `"6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 24"` but seeing as how the `System.out.print(x + " + ")` is inside the recursive loop, it ends up outputting: `"6 + 6 + 6 + 6 +  = 24"`

In the main program I have a separate line of code to output the result: 
System.out.print("= " + result);

```
public static int recursiveMultiply(int x, int y){
       //Make y positive
       if(y < 0)
           return recursiveMultiply(-x, -y);
       //base case
       if(y == 0)
           return 0;     
       //recursive case
       System.out.print(x + " + ");
       return x + recursiveMultiply(x, y-1);
```

Comment: if `y == 1` just don't print the `+`

Comment: Have a base case of 1. When you have one element it doesn't do a + on anything.

Comment: Thank you all! I got it with this! 

     `public static int recursiveMultiply(int x, int y) {
  // Make y positive
  if (y < 0)
   return recursiveMultiply(-x, -y);
  // base case
  if (y == 0)
   return 0;
  // recursive case
  if (y >= 1)
   System.out.print(x);
  if (y != 1)
   System.out.print(" + ");
  return x + recursiveMultiply(x, y - 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first 2 conditions, a `if(y>=1)` is useless

```
public static int recursiveMultiply(int x, int y) { 
    if (y < 0) {
        return recursiveMultiply(-x, -y);
    }
    if (y == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    System.out.print(x);
    if (y != 1) {
        System.out.print(" + ");
    }
    return x + recursiveMultiply(x, y - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        System.out.println("="+ recursiveMultiply(-6,-4));

}

private static int recursiveMultiply(int i, int j) {
     if (j< 0) {
            return recursiveMultiply(i, Math.abs(-j));
        }
        if (j == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        System.out.print(i);
        if (j!= 1) {
            System.out.print(" + ");
        }
        return i + recursiveMultiply(i, j - 1);

}
```